# Calling a function with new values whilst looping

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function which loops 100 times and in this loop calls a function called priceJump. When the loop is first started the price argument to this function takes an initial value of 100. But after every loop, the function produces a new price which should be passed to the priceJump function.

I have tried to code this logic unsuccessfully (code below).  The problem is that the code to produce a new price does so in a monadic way and so the value is of type m Double where m is constrained by the type class PrimMonad.

I'm probably not doing this in idiomatic Haskell which is why I am experiencing these problems so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated also. To summarise the main goal is to call the pricing function with an initial price passed in and then for every new price it generates that new price should be passed back into it.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import System.Random.MWC
import System.Random.MWC.Distributions

priceJump :: Double -- price
          -> Double -- rate
          -> Double -- vol
          -> Double -- ts
          -> Double -- rnd
          -> Double -- new price
priceJump price rate vol ts rnd = price * (1 + (rate * ts) + (vol * sqrt(ts) * rnd))

loop :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> m Double
loop gen turns price rate vol ts
  | turns <= 0 = (priceJump price rate vol ts) <$> (normal 0 1 gen)
  | turns == 100 = (priceJump price rate vol ts) <$> (normal 0 1 gen)
  | otherwise  = loop gen (turns - 1) (priceJump price rate vol ts) <$> (normal 0 1 gen) rate vol ts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking in terms of loops in Haskell will only sometimes be useful. If you want to repeat something `k` times, you should reach for `replicate` and the like. In this case, you want to repeat the function which takes a price and produces a new price 100 times (and performs some computation in some monad), then sequence those all together in a long chain.

With this in mind, the code becomes

```
loop :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> m Double
loop gen turns price rate vol ts 
  = foldr (>=>) 
          return 
          (replicate turns (\p -> priceJump p rate vol ts <$> normal 0 1 gen)) 
          price
```

It turns out that Kleisli composition (`>=> :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c`) does exactly what you need here. In this way you can see `>=>` as being like regular function composition, but inside a monad.

Another option is to generate the random values in advance, then just deal with pure values from there - i.e pure fold over the list of random seeds. But the code doesn't end up looking that different:

```
loop gen turns price rate vol ts 
   = foldr (\rnd p -> priceJump p rate vol ts rnd) price <$> 
     replicateM turns (normal 0 1 gen)
```

Comment: sidenote: This turns out to be a nice use of lists, GHC appears to be clever and stream away the lists for me so it's quite efficient.

Comment: I can't get either of your examples to compile. I must be doing something wrong. I have pasted the error message here: http://lpaste.net/156961. I wanted to use `foldr` like in your second example but I never could work out how to generate the list of random values up front.

Comment: @Mika'il The errors don't seem to be related to this code - they seem to point to the `priceJump` function. It compiled fine for me, however. Either of the functions in the answer appended to your code also compile for me. @jozefg Indeed, once you figure out which fusion rules you can rely on (I still haven't done so) it becomes easier - but `foldr / replicate` and `foldr / sequence / replicate` usually work well.

Comment: @user2407038, yes you are right. My environment got screwed up as I entered into cabal hell. I switched to stack and all is good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2407038, I have to say that your Kleisli composition example is top draw :). I came back to it today and finally grokked it! Cheers.